# Pimcore - Classificationstore add group to object

Tags: php, pimcore, pimcore-v5

Does anyone knows how to **add a Classificationstore Group** to a **DataObject**?

I’ve created a custom Class (with a **classificationstore** in it). My plan is to use the classificationstore groups to define the object (attributes of the dataobject).

But i dont know how to add a predefines group to the dataobject …

$dataobject->setAttributes( //classificationstore group ) -> this doesnt work (Attributes is the name of the classificationstore in my class)

Thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation about this subject is indeed not really clear, but you can do as followed:

```
$dataobject->getAttributes()->setActiveGroups([$groupId=>true]);
```

Comment: that doesnt worked for me. I think with ->setGroupCollectionMapping you could assign a group (or collection) to a collection but not a group to a dataObject .. am i wrong?

Comment: Mmm, I made a mistake sorry, I looked it up and it should be 'setActiveGroups'. Can you try:  $dataobject->getAttributes()->setActiveGroups([$groupId=>true]);

Comment: Thats it. Thanks a lot :D i owe you a beer